# How to monitor the status of a specific Member discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need help with monitoring a specific members online/offline status with discord.py
I want the discord bot to be constantly updating and printing the persons status.

```
def run_bot():

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} is now running")
    await updater()

@client.event
async def updater():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        for guilds in client.guilds:
            for member in guilds.members:
                if member.id == my_Member_id:
                    if member.status == discord.Status.online:
                        print(f"{member.name} is online")
                    else:
                        print(f"{member.name} is not online")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

The code I have displays the status of the person indefinitely however when the person changes their status it does not update and instead continues to display the old status

[here is a screenshot of the output keep in mind the persons status was changed multiple times while the loop ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OeRh.png)

Comment: I would suspect this is a caching issue. Maybe you should fetch the member object. E.g. `await guild.fetch_member(my_Member_id)`

Comment: using `while True` you may block all other code and it will not work. Inside loop you would need to use some `async` function and client will have to to switch to other functions and run other code - ie `async.sleep()` But it can be better to use some event or `@tasks(seconds=...)` to execute function every few seconds without using `while True`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`discord.on_presence_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_presence_update) event listener to monitor changes in status/activity of members.

```
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
    if after.id == my_Member_id:
        print('{} changed status to {}'.format(
            after.display_name,
            after.status
        ))
```

You can also use it to update locally stored member statuses and activities.